# TypeError: notes.addNote is not a function

Tags: node.js, yargs

I'm trying to debug this code too long.
I've read already about this type of error in other places, but it seems that nothing is helping.

i've tried to change thr function's names, and also in the module.exprots, didn't helped.

thank's to future saivor!

**app.js:**

```
const chalk = require('chalk')
const yargs = require('yargs')
const notes = require('./notes.js')

// Create add command
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Add a new note',
    builder: {
        title: {
            describe: 'Note title',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        },
        body: {
            describe: 'Note body',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    handler: function (argv) {
        notes.addNote(argv.title, argv.body)
    }
})

// Create remove command
yargs.command({
    command: 'remove',
    describe: 'Remove a note',
    builder: {
            title:{
                describe: 'Note title',
                demandOption: true,
                type: 'string'
            }
    },
    handler: function (argv) {
        notes.removeNote(argv.title)       
    }
})

yargs.parse()
```

**notes.js:**

```
const fs = require('fs')

const getNotes = function () {
    return 'Your notes...'
}

const addNote = function (title, body) {
    const notes = loadNotes()
    const duplicateNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title === title
    })

    if (duplicateNotes.length === 0) {
        notes.push({
            title: title,
            body: body
        })
        saveNotes(notes)
        console.log('New note added!')
    } else {
        console.log('Note title taken!')
    }
}

const saveNotes = function (notes) {
    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(notes)
    fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', dataJSON)
}

const loadNotes = function () {
    try {
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString()
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    } catch (e) {
        return []
    }
}

const removeNote = function(title) {
    const notes = loadNotes()
    const notesToKeep = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title !== title
    })

    saveNotes(notesToKeep)


module.exports = {
    getNotes: getNotes,
    addNote: addNote,
    removeNote: removeNote
    }
}
```

**error that i'm getting:**

TypeError: notes.addNote is not a function
at Object.handler (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Web Development\node.js\Hello\notes-app\app.js:22:15)
at Object.runCommand (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Web Development\node.js\Hello\notes-app\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:214:40)
at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Web Development\node.js\Hello\notes-app\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1154:4
1)
at Object.parse (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Web Development\node.js\Hello\notes-app\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:599:25)
at Object. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Web Development\node.js\Hello\notes-app\app.js:60:7)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)

Answer (score 1):

Why have you put your module.exports inside the removeNote, place it outside the function.
Or if you want to use arrow function you can use as follow.

```
const fs = require('fs')

exports.getNotes = () => {
    return 'Your notes...'
}

exports.addNote = (title, body) => {
    const notes = loadNotes()
    const duplicateNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title === title
    })

    if (duplicateNotes.length === 0) {
        notes.push({
            title: title,
            body: body
        })
        saveNotes(notes)
        console.log('New note added!')
    } else {
        console.log('Note title taken!')
    }
}

const saveNotes = function (notes) {
    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(notes)
    fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', dataJSON)
}

const loadNotes = function () {
    try {
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString()
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    } catch (e) {
        return []
    }
}

exports.removeNote =(title) => {
    const notes = loadNotes()
    const notesToKeep = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title !== title
    })

    saveNotes(notesToKeep)
}
```

Comment: Lack of concentration.
Thank you Mushariar!